# Angularjs Change Api access_token with $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Hello I'm looking for a way to change the `access_token` in my UserApi-Resource. For example.

The token is stored in the cookie, but the resource will only read the cooke once, if 
the resource is created.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mnjsUser', ['ngResource']).factory('UserApi', ['$resource', '$cookieStore',
  function($resource, $cookieStore) {
    var token = $cookieStore.get('token') || {}; // line will only be executed once (page refresh)

    return $resource('http://localhost:8000/api/me.json', {'access_token': token.access_token}, {
    });
  }]);
```

Here is the usage in my controller

```
angular.module('mnjsProfileController', []).controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserApi',
  function($scope, UserApi) {
    $scope.user = UserApi.get();
  }]);
```

Is it possible to create a `UserApi.init()` function?

How can I inject / refresh my `access_token` before a request starts? At the moment my `UserApi` will not noticed if the cookie is refreshed.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to make a change to the token so it is a function and call it each time you make the request with the resource.

Comment: You mean something like that? https://gist.github.com/createproblem/5010fb47aaa465b42287

Comment: No. that's what you have. Something like {accesstoken:getToken()}. Or make the token another service and return it via a function. Am on phone hence short message.